# jquery datepicker show text that is different from value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am currently using the datepicker. Since sometime I would like to show some text rather than the date which I select from the datepicker, does someone know whether there is a way to do that ? Many thanks !

For example:
If 2015/01/01 is a holiday and I select this date, I would like to show the holiday name over the input element rather than 2015/01/01. When I submit, the value (2015/01/01) will still be passed into the server.

I have searched over the google, but haven't found out a good solution yet.

Comment: You're going to have to write something in order to do this since the datepicker doesn't have that option built-in. Have you tried anything (other than Googling) yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the selected date in another field, and use the `onSelect` event to check and overwrite the selected value.

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    altField: "#actualDate",
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        if (dateText.substring(0, 5) == "04/01") {
            inst.input.val("april fools!");
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="datepicker" type="text">
<br>
<input id="actualDate" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest would be to completely implement your own date picker.

Next is to hack datepicker, e.g.

```
var that = this;
this.$input.datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
        // get value, e.g. "2015-10-14"
        // check if that date is mapped to any holiday
        that.$input.val("St. Patrick Day 2015");
    },
});
```

Also when you get this.$input.val() to use it, have to manually translate "St. Patrick Day 2015" back to "2015-10-14".

Kinda ugly vs build your own.